# Why use VARCHAR for names and CHAR for passwords

Tags: mysql, char, varchar

I dont understand why the following script:

```
first_name VARCHAR(20),
last_name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
email VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
password CHAR(40) NOT NULL,
```

has names etc as VARCHAR and password as CHAR.. is it because of how it is retrieved, i.e. names come together, like first name comes with surname, whereas passwords are individual.. im not sure..

Also, in MySQL is script the same thing as code in Python?

Comment: You should ask whomever wrote it, but my guess is that `password` actually contains a hash and not a string. You should post some sample values.

Comment: @DourHighArch okay say for example the name is Peter, the surname is Smith, the email is petersmith@yahoo.com and the password is Peter123, I know that with VARCHAR the length can change, whereas with CHAR its fixed so even though the password Peter123 has 8 characters, CHAR(40) means that the remaining 32 will be space characters. _But what i dont understand is why its only the password as CHAR/ not VARCHAR_

Comment: That would be true only if the password is stored as a string, and my guess it isn't. Hashes are always the same length for all strings; for example, the hashes of “Peter123” and “supercalifragilisticsexpealidocious” will be the same length, no padding or spaces will be added. Is that what your database contains? Post the actual database values, not something you made up.

Comment: @DourHighArch I've only been given the script and I'm trying to understand the reasons behind each command. Later I _have_ to make up the values as another task.

Answer (score 3):

Varchar is variable length and Char is fixed length.

Since name,last_name,email generally varies in length, its best to use variable length so only as much storage is used as needed; password length generally depends on the restrictions/conditions as imposed  by the application and may be fixed when stored(eg stored as md5 hex string or so), so Char data type is used. If content is of fixed size, char has better performance.

For more, please refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/char.html

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a `sha1` hash. The hash-algorithm was popular in earlier years by developers. `sha1` encrypted passwords always have the fixed length of 40 characters, `sha1` is considered as unsafe nowadays and in latter versions of PHP `password_verify` and `password_hash` functions has been implemented, which use internally `blowfish` or `bcrypt` (60 characters). If the password length is always fixed, like with sha1 `CHAR` can be used for better performance.